# Basic operations of python's re.finditer() function

Tags: python, regex, search, analysis

I was wondering if anybody can tell me how the `finditer()` function from the `re` library works.Specifically the basic operations behind the function.

I tried to `Step Into` the function call using an IDE but I don't really know what's going on once it starts going from function to function in 3 different files (`re.py`, `sre_compile.py`, and `sre_parse.py`)

The reason I want to know is because I feel like the basic operations of my source code is comparisons (it's an implementation of fuzzy search), so I need to be able to determine how many operations `finditer()` makes on a string with `n` characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unanswerable. Regular expressions are a language; therefore, `finditer` and other regexp-executing functions don't intrinsically have a fixed complexity. For example, the regexp `a` is linear, `a*` is not, and `(a*)*` is an abomination.

EDIT on account of being wrong: Python uses a backtracking algorithm.

Comment: I just want to know how it finds the iterable indices. like if it does some sort of horspool's matching algorithm, or if it goes character by character doing a bruteforce match, etc.So this would mean that it uses the Thompson's algorithm with automaton? Thank you.

Comment: No, apparently it uses the same old backtracking. Not sure if it uses some kind of string search algorithm to make it more efficient; probably not.

Comment: What do you think about this Amadan? It says python uses a scanner. https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a82fc1f366b4/Modules/_sre.c

Comment: I think you can see exactly the optimisations [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a82fc1f366b4/Modules/_sre.c#l1533). Note that given it's regexp, you can only optimise for the beginning of the match if it is constant (e.g. `bana(na*)` would skip according to `bana`; `(ho)*` won't get optimised AFAIK.

Comment: I actually emailed the supposed author of _sre.c. He said that hg (the host for the cpython source that has that file) got it wrong and that I should send an email to "Fredrik Lundh if you can get hold of him, or Matthew Barnett" unfortunately. However, seeing as you made a link to the actual lines of code for the 'USE_FAST_SEARCH' function, I do believe it uses Thompson's construction since it references 'states' in the functions body. Additionally, I'm pretty sure that regular backtracking isn't used because it wouldn't be nearly as efficient as the current way python is handling the regexes